# Error when opening tpus page on google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-tpu

When I opened the URL "https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/tpus?project=..." I get the error below

> "There was an error while loading /compute/tpus?folder=&project=.... Please try again. Request ID: ...".

There is no other information given except that error message.

I have tried deleting the project and making a new one. Same error.

Answer (score 3):

Is the Cloud TPU API enabled for your project? If not you can enable it first and then you'll be able to see the proper page. This is an issue our UI team is aware of internally and they are in the process of fixing it.

Comment: Enabling Cloud TPU API fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, does the  url literally end in `?project=...` or did you change the name to an ellipsis for the example? If the former, try replacing the ellipsis with the project name. Otherwise, try removing the parameter string (everything after `/tpus`) - this should resolve to the TPU page of the last project you viewed.

Comment: Ellipsis added by me. I use the console menu to navigate to the page

Comment: Interesting. Is the [Cloud TPU API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/tpu.googleapis.com) enabled for the project in question? If not, that's probably the issue.